# How can I search in source code of Visual Studio solution with AND / OR?

Tags: visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2013

In **Visual Studio** solutions, how can you search through the entire source using more than 1 search term (for example: search for files where "fibonacci" `AND` "sum" is contained and display the results - likewise with `OR`)?

I know you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, enter the first keyword and then search in the displayed results again (via: "Search in files" option), but it is not the same - and what if you need more than 2 terms to look for?

For example: If I am looking for:

`"`Get`"` `AND` `(` `"`sum`"` `OR` `"`product"`)`

which will find properties like

- **Get**Cartesian**Product**
- **Get**Fibonacci**Sum**

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on regex and put in `Fibonacci.*(Procuct|Sum)` as the search expression:

[image]

This expression will find all instances of `Fibonacci` followed by zero or more characters and then followed by either `Product` or `Sum`.

There are many useful references for regular expressions; one of my favorites is this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Yes - Good idea! The only disadvantage is the regex syntax for which I usually use a regex editor. Do you know if there is any extension available which includes that in VS so it is more comfortable to use? (either RegEx editor to be used seamlessly or a search+replace extension for the source code)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  "The only disadvantage is the regex syntax for which I usually use a regex editor."  You can just type it in like I gave it to you.

Comment: Well, the example given, is "fibonacci" OR "sum" OR "product". How would you do "fibonacci" and ("sum" or "product") ? I.e. returning results being either fibonacci and sum or fibonacci and product. If you can answer that, I am happy with the answer

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  When you use the "Find" tool, it locates all instances that match the expression.  So if you used the expression I gave you, it would find any of the three values, `fibonacci`, `sum`, or `product`.  If you click "find next", it will go to the next instance of one of those three.  I don't get how you could have `fibonacci` AND one of the other two.  Either you have `fibonacci` or you don't.

Comment: If you want to find properties in the code like GetFibonacciProcuct, GetFibonacciSum then you might want to look for ("Get" & "Procuct") | ("Get & "Sum") - finding both. But that does not work with the RegEx find, at least I could not find out how.

Comment: Try this expression: `Fibonacci.*(Procuct|Sum)`

Comment: Thank you for the link, it contains a very comprehensive RegEx tutorial and reference. An additional tool I'd like to share with you is an extension for VS I just found: Regex tester - it works for VS2012 and VS2013 and allows to test regular expressions. Install it, then open it via "View -> Other Windows -> RegEx tester". I also found nice stand-alone tools for RegEx in another SO question: [RegEx query builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991264/regex-query-builder). It supports you creating search queries.